# Periodic solutions of this systems

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I need to prove that the system of differential equations
$$ \dot x  = y  \\
 \dot y  = 1+x^2-(1-x)y $$  doesn't contain periodic solutions.
I know the Bendixon criteria (that is to have div no sign changing), but, the divergence of this system is $x-1$, and I can´t sure that this will never change the sign (at $x=1$ there will be a change). How can I do that?

Comment: I find periodic solutions for $x=1$ and $y<-2$.

Comment: No, false alarm it doesn't have periodic solutions for $x=1$ and $y<-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fr any solution, $x$ is unbounded. I will use $x'$ for $\dot x$.
$$
x''=y'=1+x^2-(1-x)y=1+x^2-(1-x)x'\implies x''+(1-x)x'=1+x^2\ge1.
$$
Integrating
$$
x'+x-\frac{x^2}{2}\ge t+c_1 \text{ for some constant }c_1.
$$
Then
$$
x'+x\ge t+c_1+\frac{x^2}{2}\ge t+c_1.
$$
Multiplying by $e^t$:
$$
(e^t\,x)'\ge(t+c_1)\,e^t.
$$
Integrate and obtain that $x(t)$ grows at least as $t^2/2$ as $t\to\infty$.